# Is this normal? Badge not going through as awarded

Tags: support, bug, badges

It's been a couple of days now since I think I earned this badge now and somehow it has not been awarded. I think it may be a bug, because I stopped asking questions for a while.

[image]

Comment: For what I can tell, the record is positive

Comment: See that x next to "need positive question record"? Means you haven't fulfilled that criteria for the badge.

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions?

Comment: Not that I recall

Comment: @Chisko you have 3 deleted questions

Comment: 3 shouldn't be enough, unless they're also closed and also negative (even also one or the other is not sufficient, have to be > 6).